# Function completes it execution before completion handler finished

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to return the result that is calculated  from HelperConnection.shared.getInfo(). But I always get nil in result variable(also after group.wait). How stop the current function execution until HelperConnection.shared.getInfo() finished?

```
  func install(lists:[String]) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var result : String!

    if lists.count != 0 {
        for i in lists {
            group.enter()
            HelperConnection.shared.getInfo(str: i, completion: { (str) in
                if str == "1" {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        result = str
                        group.leave()
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        result = "Hello"
                        group.leave()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
    print(result)
    print(".........")
    group.wait(timeout: .now() + 5)
    print(result)
    return result
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `notify` instead of `wait` and add a completion handler. Forcing asynchronous tasks to be synchronous is bad practice.

```
func install(lists:[String], completion: @escaping: (String)->Void) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var result = ""

    if lists.isEmpty { (completion("")) }
    for i in lists {
        group.enter()
        HelperConnection.shared.getInfo(str: i, completion: { str in
            defer(group.leave())
            if str == "1" {
               result = str
            } else {
               result = "Hello"
            }
        })
    }       

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print(".........")
        print(result)
        completion(result)
   }
}
```

Comment: I included the below code in program. But the print statement get not executed.
     
  group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            print(result)
  }

Comment: The line is not executed only if `lists` is empty.

Comment: I checked that. But my list is not empty. I added a print above the  if lists.isEmpty. Now the out put i got is
 ["user1","user2"]
nil
.........

Comment: i didn't write completion(result). My function definition is  func install(lists:[String]) { }.

Comment: Does `HelperConnection.shared.getInfo` return anything?

Comment: Now it works. But i want to use the result string from install like this.
let str = install(lists:listsOfUser). If use completion handler how i obtain the str. I want to use that for evaluate a case in switch.

Comment: like switch( install(lists:listsOfUser)) { case "User": }

Comment: The usage of `result` is ambiguous anyway as it gets overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: This is just wrote for just initial implementation. So please don't consider usage of  result.

Comment: Is there is any way to do that without completion handler? i want to use like switch( install(lists:listsOfUser)) { case "User": }

Comment: No, it’s not due to the asynchronous behavior. Put the switch in the completion handler of `install(lists:`

Comment: let a = group.wait(wallTimeout: .now()+5)
        if a == .timedOut {
            print("hello")
            return false
        } else {
            print("hai")
            return result
        }

Comment: Once again, *Forcing asynchronous tasks to be synchronous is bad practice.*